# hiding section name and include it in toc

Tags: table-of-contents

I tried to find a solution, but I cant.

I'm writing my thesis, and all my sections are numerated arabic.
I have no problem displaying them in TOC.
Before those section i have several pages numerated roman which I havent defined as sections, because i don't need a heading on those pages.

How can I include those roman numerated pages in TOC, but without defining their title, or at least hide it?

Far example, I have \section{Intro} numerated arabic and displayed in toc as 1. Intro
Before that page i have page numerated roman, and only table on it. I dont need a heading. But I would wish to be displayed in toc without number, and with roman numeration.
So the result would be

> Very big table....I
>
> 1. Intro..........1

I just have problem with labeling a page but without showing its name when printing, but it must show in toc, and be numerated according to its number on the bottom.

EDIT:
These are some of my packages and codes

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
University of bla bla.
My name

\newpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}
Stuff about my supervisor and my university

\newpage
Only very big table here

\newpage 

\textbf{Content}
\def\contentsname{\empty}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\newpage

\section*{Symbols}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Symbols}

\newpage

\section{Intro}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\end{document}
```

So, I would wish to include in TOC stuff about my university and supervisor, and also that very big table - for example, with a title in TOC that i choose, and without that title appearing on a page with table.

Answer (score 1):

This table seems special, and therefore may differ in terms of the setting relative to other tables (in the List of Tables) as well as sectional headings (in the Table of Contents). That's what I've done below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftdot}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\l@specialtable{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{0pt}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
University of bla bla.
My name

\newpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}
Stuff about my supervisor and my university

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{specialtable}{Only very big table here}% Insert table in ToC
Only very big table here

\newpage 

{\let\oldsection\section
 \renewcommand{\section}{\oldsection*}
 \tableofcontents}

\newpage

\section*{Symbols}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Symbols}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Intro}

\end{document}
```

`\l@specialtable` defines how `specialtable` entries are set within the "List of" environments. I've just set it to print like any other section (level 1), but without the formatting. It sets the entry in the default font, but that can be changed, like almost everything else.

Comment: Uh, thats great!
How can i also add page (roman number I) about my university and supervisor into the TOC, to be displayed as "INFO....I"?

Comment: @neznam: Since `specialtable` is really set to do "nothing", you could use `\addcontentsline{toc}{specialtable}{<other stuff>}` anywhere. Perhaps rename all references to `specialtable` to something like `specialentry`, so it has more meaning.